# How to find the latest two created files date in a folder?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder where a set of two new different CSV files with different names are created daily, and I need to get the dates of the latest two created each day to verify if the dates correspond to the day previous.

Im currently using a code that I got to set up searching through several other posts but I'm getting a error that states:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'date'

```
import os
import glob
import time
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import timedelta

yesterday = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)).date()
print('yesterdays date:', yesterday)

def test_modified(filename):
    delta = time.time() - os.path.getmtime(filename)
    delta = delta / (60*60*24)
    if delta < 1:
        return True
    return False

path='C:\\testfolder\\'

for file in mfiles:
    filetime = [mfile for mfile in glob.glob(path+'*.csv') if test_modified(mfile)]  
    if filetime.date() == yesterday:
        print('The file has yesterdays date')
    else:
        print('The files doesnt have yesterdays date')
```

My guess is that I must include a Date attribute with the filetime list, but I don't know how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You defined `filetime` as a list. Why are you surprised that a list has no method `date()`?

Comment: Check you code again. Is this a copy/paste from somewhere? As already pointed out, you assign a list to `filetime`,of course it does not have a `.date()` method. Before the `for` loop you do the same list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

I think these 2 lines cause the problem:

```
filetime = [mfile for mfile in glob.glob(path+'*.csv') if test_modified(mfile)]  
if filetime.date() == yesterday:
```

Your **filetime** variable after execute the list comprehension is just a list string of file csv path and it doesn't have any date attribute.

This thread maybe help you resolve this problem
[How do I get file creation and modification date/times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-do-i-get-file-creation-and-modification-date-times)

Also

This line `[mfile for mfile in glob.glob(path+'*.csv') if test_modified(mfile)]` is duplicated and I think you should check the logic at this line again.